# considers a probability vector v containing the probabilities of jumping to each vertex

Tags: grammatical-number

Should I use "*probabilities*" or "*probability*" in the following sentence?

> Consider a probability vector *v* containing the probabilities of jumping to each vertex.

Comment: This appears to be a fragment, not a sentence; and it's not clear which word you are asking about -- is it the first "probability" or the second "probabilities" you are considering?

Comment: @AndrewLeach  'consider' is imperative.

Comment: are the probabilities (the coordinates of the vector presumably) distinct or are they all identical?

Comment: my problem is about the second probabilities. Each vertex has a probability and they are placed in vector v. Should I use probabilities?

Answer (score 2):

For each vertex, there's only one probability.  So you should say "... containing the probability of jumping to each vertex".

Answer (score 0):

Since a probability vector is a nonnegative vector whose coordinates sum to 1 ... If that is what you are talking about "a probability vector" would do it. It's much more a maths question .

**edit:** following your edit, it's more clear (it initially looked like your *v* was standing for *versus*), then, since in a probability vector there are several probabilities, the plural is ok for the second occurrence.

**edit #2:** I guess you are talking about being in one given vertex, which is associated to a vector giving the probabilities for going to *one of the other vertices*, right ?